# How to set ps-end-cut-regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, pretty-print

I often use `ps-print-buffer` to print out files, but I don't want the first few lines of the buffer to be printed.  Here's the beginning of the buffer:

```
# -*- mode: org; -*-
# Last updated: <2017/12/12 18:37>

* First header
```

Say I want to cut everything up to the line `* First header`.  I set

```
 (setq ps-begin-cut-regexp "^# -\\*- mode: org; -\\*-$")
```

and the first line does not appear on the printout.  But how to set `ps-end-cut-regexp`?  I tried

```
  (setq ps-end-cut-regexp "^\\* .*")
  (setq ps-end-cut-regexp "^# Last updated: <.*>$")
```

But neither works: the second line (`# Last updated: <2017/12/12 18:37>`) appears on the printout.  What regex should I use to cut the first three lines?

Comment: Dunno, but did you try `^\*` or `^$`?

Comment: Yes, I have.  They don't work either.